# How to show loading div in my view with json result

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a loading div in my MVC application. so i am getting json result value and showing a kendo grid. Because of more data it is taking time so for that purpose i used this but unfortunately it's not working.
Below is my code
This is my script used in the view

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
        var action = "@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/ChartInitialDataBinding/")";
        $('#spinner').show()
        $.getJSON(action, null, function(something) 
        {
            $('#spinner').hide()
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my loading div

```html
<div id="spinner" style="display:none">
        Loading...
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should know from documentation, that [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success) is just wrap above `ajax` jquery function.

So don't you want to put your spinner not only in this function, but with all ajax requests? I think it's better, becouse you can define this in onle place and don't thik anymoreabout this problem.

In your `Layout` View just add this script, after your jquery library loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#spinner').show()
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#spinner').hide()
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#spinner').hide()
        }
    });
});
```

You can read more about [`$.ajaxSetup` here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of things to check/fix:

-add semicolons after $('#spinner').show() and $('#spinner').hide()

-make sure you have included jQuery

-check if spinner is in view when removing "display:none"

Comment: I used semicolon for show and hide but it is showing when grid displays.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want your spinner to display until grid data is loaded?

Comment: yes right i want that when actionresult function call then loading should start and when it's finished loading should finish

Comment: don't know why it's taking more time to load the page. i put the blockui thing in layout.cshtml page so it should work for all the views but not able to find that takes time to load the page.

Comment: Hello everyone is there anyway to catch a javascript or jquery function before calling actionresult of controller??

Comment: Hi. This is what teo-van-kot just answered. You can bind to jQuery's ajax event globally.

Comment: Hi  i checked through debugging and got to know that my action result taking some time to response so i need here before calling my action result some jquery function should run so i can show my loading image here.